# Trying to run a for loop on a html element while using bs4 but it does not iterate

Tags: python, html, parsing, url, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the country names, market names and the url's from the given website below by using BeautifulSoup library. I am trying to get countrynames by a for loop but it only gives me the first one.

I was expecting it to iterate through all countries but it does not do that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://www.freshplaza.com/europe/content/retailers/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
retailer_links = soup.find_all('div', {'id':'retailers'} )
for el in retailer_links:
    print(el.h2.text)

for el in retailer_links:
    if el.h2.text == 'Afghanistan':
        print(True)
    else: 
        print(False)



for el in retailer_links:
    if el.h2.text == 'Hong Kong':
        print(True)
    else: 
        print(False)
```

Comment: And what debugging have you done? What does `retailer_links` contain? Is there anything more you could provide?

Comment: IDs are suppoosed to be unique, so there should only be one `id="retailers"` and you shouldn't need a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`el.h2` means the `h2` attribute of the element, not the `<h2>` elements that are inside the DIV.

You can use `soup.select()` to get all the `h2` elements inside the `retailers` div:

```
retailer_links = soup.select("div#retailers h2")
for el in retailer_links:
    text = el.get_text()
    if text == 'Afghanistan':
        print('Afghanistan found')
    elif text == 'Hong Kong'
        print('Hong Kong found')
```